# Zend Studio for Eclipse-- Run/Debug a PHP Web Page is not working

Tags: zend-studio

I am using Zend Studio for Eclipse 6.1.

I have all the AMP stack installed.

However, when I load the ExampleProject in Zend Studio for Eclipse, and right click on a script, choose run as-PHP web page, I got a "The Page cannot be found" error.

This is the setting I set in Eclipse,

[http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SajMHPj1-9I/AAAAAAAAEjk/itoOfggAuSs/s400/zend%20debugger%20error.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/VZNZSaVP6oG3Bhc7HfwJlQ?feat=embedwebsite)

and this is the error.

[http://lh5.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SajMHIMoCTI/AAAAAAAAEjs/5Oca5QrVPgE/s400/the%20page%20cant%20be%20found.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/y9ALHJE9SKSWINRXuWq0jQ?feat=embedwebsite)

However, when I run as PHP script, I didn't encounter any error at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache is running but seems that the URL doesn't match with your server public folder, and that it's giving you the error you show, a 404 Page Not Found.

Check if your project source files are in the right place, normally in the *htdocs* folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have fully figured out how to debug PHP webpage in Zend Studio for Eclipse.

Here's [the link](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-debug-php-file-as-webpage-using.html).